# How can I update image in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a table which contains the path  of image. In controller I have this method

```
public string uploadimage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            string path = "-1";
            int random = r.Next();
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                if (extension.ToLower().Equals(".jpg") || extension.ToLower().Equals(".jpeg") || extension.ToLower().Equals(".png"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), random + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                        file.SaveAs(path);
                        path = "~/Content/Images/" + random + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        path = "-1";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Only jpg ,jpeg or png formats are acceptable....'); </script>");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Please select a file'); </script>");
                path = "-1";
            }
            return path;
        }
```

I used it succefully in Create ActionResult, but I couldn't find a right way to use in Edit ActionResult. I tried this code:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Location,Image")] Restaurant restaurant, HttpPostedFileBase imgfile)
        {
            string path = uploadimage(imgfile);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                restaurant.Image = path;
                db.Entry(restaurant).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Success", "Home");
            }
            return View(restaurant);
        }
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work because when I chose and add new photo but it says that Image is required.Edit View:

```
    @model RestaurantApp.Models.Restaurant

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Изменить</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Restaurants", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Ресторан</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" id="imgfile" name="imgfile" class="btn btn-info" />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

My Restaurant Model:

```
public class Restaurant
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Имя Ресторана")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Адрес Ресторана")]
        public string Location { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Логотип Ресторана")]
        public string Image { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("Restaurant")]
        public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("Restaurant")]
        public ICollection<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
    }
```

I think it means that Image path is null but I tried also to use db.Add method but it didn't work too. I modified Edit View as Create View so the problem is not in View. Can you suggest me how to solve this problem?

Comment: please post your full edit view

Comment: I added Edit View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it says that Image is required.

Image is showing as required because in your view you don't have an input field for `Model.Image`, what you have is an input field for `imgFile`.

To fix this, you just have to move `restaurant.Image = path;` before `ModelState.IsValid` because that's when the evaluation for correct model properties take place.

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Location,Image")] Restaurant restaurant, HttpPostedFileBase imgfile)
{
   string path = uploadimage(imgfile);

   // move this here, so it has value before ModelState.IsValid
   restaurant.Image = path;

   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      db.Entry(restaurant).State = EntityState.Modified;
      db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Success", "Home");
   }
   return View(restaurant);
}
```

Then in your view, just add the Restaurant properties as hidden, so they wouldn't be modified. Use `@Html.HiddenFor()`.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Restaurants", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

   @*Add these properties*@
   @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Id)
   @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Name)
   @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Location)

   <div class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
         <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" id="imgfile" name="imgfile" class="btn btn-info" />
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="btn btn-default" />
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
}
```

Comment: I had other properties I just didn't show them. Moving restaurant.Image = path; doesn't work. It says Image required yet.

Comment: @GulzhanatZhumazhanova Wait-- so you have an Model.Image field in the view? Will you include in the question, your current view code.

Comment: I added current view

Comment: Does the warning message appear on the HTML and doesn't make a POST to your controller?

Comment: Yes, it appears on the HTML and doesn't make a POST

Comment: I used debug and it shows that ModelState.IsValid has value "false"

Comment: @GulzhanatZhumazhanova will you post your full restaurant model? Thanks

Comment: during POST, does Id,Name,Location properties have values?

Comment: I solve my problem) I just removed [Required] functions

Comment: @GulzhanatZhumazhanova you're welcome, good luck with the project..